# Hide youtube annotations

Tags: css, video, youtube

I'm a french designer (so, sorry for my english mistakes) and I'm trying to create an interactive video with different videos hosted on youtube.
These videos already use the youtube 'annotations' or 'cards', but I want to hide them to create my own solution.

Basically I just want to show two divs at a certain timecode of the video to allow user to click on one of them to go to a new url. This thing works.

**My question is simple : how can I hide the existing annotations?**
I've tried with css, but it doesn't seem to work…
I'm not a full-time developer, so if you know a simple solution, I would be happy to know it :)

Here is the code

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'mVwQFmKc7mA',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'iv_load_policy': 3 },
      events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(displayNewDivs, 2000);*/
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function displayNewDivs() {
    // HERE THE CODE TO SHOW NEW DIVS
  }

</script>
```

Thank you very much!